# Iterating through each letter of a string

Tags: ruby, iteration

I am trying to iterate through each letter of a string to print out a word.

```
greeting = "hello"
extract = 0
letter = greeting[extract]

while extract < greeting.length
  p letter
  extract += 1
end
```

The result is `"h", "h", "h" ,"h", "h"` instead of hello. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://code-maven.com/iterate-over-character-of-a-string-in-ruby

Comment: There is also a built-in method for this, `each_char`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're printing inside the loop a variable that has been initialized and which its value has never changed, that's why is always printing "h".

It would be different if you print it inside the loop as the "counter" (`extract`) goes increasing:

```
greeting = "hello"
extract = 0

while extract < greeting.length
  p greeting[extract]
  extract += 1
end
```

If you wanna take another step and use built-in Ruby functions, you can use `each_char`:

```
greeting = 'hello'
greeting.each_char(&method(:p))
# same output
```

Comment: `greeting.each_char { |c| p c }` might even be easier to remember. BTW, passing a block to `chars` is deprecated and results in a warning.

Comment: Now I see _"If a block is given, which is a deprecated form, works the same as each_char."_, didn't know that. Thanks @Stefan!